# Спискок со своими стилями в TinyMCE WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

Как сделать в TinyMCE кнопку списка с выбором своих стилей для `ul`?

Помогите, плз, с кодом js-функции, которая может оборачивать выделенный текст, аналогично стандартному поведению, но добавляя при этом нужный стиль тегу `ul`.
*Саму кнопку делать могу, а вот с javascript-ом не могу разобраться (основная проблема - корректное оборачивание многострочного текста).*

Подробнее:
Хочу иметь в панели кнопку, аналогичную стандартной (или в стандартную добавить), с выбором стиля списка *(в этом списке иконки от fontawesome - не обязательны)*

[image]

чтобы выделенный текст
`пункт1
 пункт2
 пункт3`

Преобразовался в код напр

```html
<ul class="mystarstyle">
<li>пункт1</li>
<li>пункт2</li>
<li>пункт3</li>
</ul>
```

(наказания стилей- свои, независимые от названий fontawesome)

PS. Если есть плагин к ВП c таким функционалом - буду благодарен за подсказку.